# Looping through employee IDs on a separate tab to paste to a cell in a Total Rewards Statement and Create a PDF

Tags: excel, vba

Looking to create a macro for what the title says, the employee IDs and the Total rewards statement are on separate tabs.

The total rewards statement is driven by a cell (C9:D9) that houses the unique employee ID

Where have I gone wrong? I am getting a 'variable not defined' compile error for the EmployeeIdRange

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Create_PDFs_Loop()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Let LastRow = SSSource.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Dim i As Long
    Dim EEID As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    '12 indicates row where employee IDs start (B12 in SSSource worksheet)
    For i = 12 To LastRow
        EmployeeIdRange = Range("B" & i).Value
        SSSource.EmployeeIdRange.Value.Copy SSDest.Range("C9:D9")
        FileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\PDFExport"
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, FileName
    Next i

End Sub
```

Solved!!

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Create_PDFs_Loop()

Dim FileName As String
Dim Startcell As Long

Let Startcell = 12
'12 indicates row where employee IDs start (B12 in SSSource worksheet)

With Application
    .StatusBar = "Running Macro..."
    .DisplayAlerts = False
End With

Do Until SSSource.Range("B" & Startcell).Value = ""

    SSSource.Range("B" & Startcell).Copy SSDest.Range("C9:D9")
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, FileName:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Total Rewards Statement_" & SSDest.Range("B9").Value
    Startcell = Startcell + 1
        
Loop

With Application
    .StatusBar = "Macro Complete"
    .StatusBar = ""
    .DisplayAlerts = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It's as the error message says - you have not declared the variable `EmployeeIdRange` and you have `Option Explicit`, so all variables must be declared.   FYI `SSSource.EmployeeIdRange.Value.Copy` seems wrong, but it's not clear exactly what the code is intended to do, so it's difficult to suggest a fix.

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what is wrong - you have not declared the variable `EmployeeIDRange`.